# Openntf Domino API Plugins missing from one Notes Template

Tags: xpages

I have one Notes Template ntf in which the Openntf Domino API plugins do not appear in 'Plug-in Dependencies' library, eg. org.openntf.domino.xsp etc. They are installed on both the server and the local machine, as we use XPiNC. They appear in any a new application created from the template and they appear in other templates and other nsfs. The plugin xml references them but they are still not in there.

```
 <import optional="true" plugin="org.openntf.domino.xsp"/>
```

The Notes template is on a server. How do I get them in there or solve the problem, I have tried various import methods to no avail, this area is not a strong point for me.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Where are you expecting to see them? They're not pulled into the NSF / NTF at all. "import" doesn't refer to importing files into the NSF, it just means to require it at runtime. For XPiNC, everything runs on the client, so the server is irrelevant.

Comment: Sorry, my misunderstanding about how it works. As stated above though, they don't appear in Plug In Dependencies as they do in all my other applications, I don't know if that is significant but the outcome is I cannot important into a Class e.g. import org.openntf.domino.Session.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use an NTF with XPinc. The status bar will show a message about it not running. You can have an NSF with a TEMPLATE NAME that will refresh other database that inherit from that template. If you need the NTF for database creation purposes, develop in an NSF that has a TEMPLATE NAME from which the NTF inherits. (EG: MyAppDev). THe NTF then has a TEMPLATE NAME from whihc other databases inherit (EG: MyApp)

Comment: Thanks, yes I realise the limitations of NTF especially with XPiNC, but the that isn't my problem, I can easily refresh an NSF from the NTF. The problem is the missing ODA plugins from my long established Template which I am just adding XPage functionality to resuliting in errors all all over the show in the java code.

Answer (score 0):

If you're getting an error that you cannot import a class in Domino Designer, there are two places to look.

1. The library needs "ticking" on the Xsp Properties. This tells the application that it needs that particular plugin at runtime. If it's missing on the server, you'll get an error.
2. The library needs installing for every Domino Designer that's going to be used to work on the application. Upgrading Notes to a new version will invariably disable previously installed plugins, so you need to go to File > Application > Application Management.... Custom plugins are in the second category, and if they have a red circle crossed through, it's disabled and needs re-enabling.

Comment: Thanks Paul, yes I am well versed in all that. This is one application out of several ie. the only one in which the ODA plugins do not appear in the Dependencies. They appear in any application created from the NTF. Not to worry, I will move on and work round the errors in the java classes.